# Java how to combine text and combo filters to show data in tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have two class:

```
public class Personal {

private int id;
private String name;
private String dni;
private double amount;
private int idArea;

public Personal(int id, String name, String dni, double amount, int area){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.idArea = area;
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

And

```
public class Area {
private int id;
private String name;

public Departamento(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
//getters and setters..}
```

Then in my controller I have this metodh to populate and filter tableview via a textbox`

```
    private void InitTable() {
    MySqlPersonaDAO daoP = new MySqlPersonaDAO(Conexion.getConnection());

    try{
        listaPersona = daoP.getAll();
    }catch (DAOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FilteredList<Personal> listaFiltrada = new FilteredList<>(listaPersona, p -> true);
    // ADD listener to text
    txtFiltrarPersona.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        listaFiltrada.setPredicate(personal -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }

            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if (personal.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches name.
            } else if (personal.getDni().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true; // Filter matches DNI.
            }
            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });

    SortedList<Personal> sortedData = new SortedList<>(listaFiltrada);
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(myTable.comparatorProperty());

    try {
        myTable.setItems(sortedData);
         }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");`
```

Im newbie in Java. So far my code works: Populate tableview(SQL) and filter by name or dni probability in not the best way.

**My Problem:** 
Now I have to add a second filter in a combobox, to show in my tableview people depending on area and I have no idea how to make it.
I need a second filterList or can I use the same(listaFiltrada)?

My attempt:

```
comboArea.setOnAction((event) -> {
        Area selectedArea = comboArea.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


        MySqlPersonaDAO daoP = new MySqlPersonaDAO(Conexion.getConnection());
        try {
            NewObservableList = daoP.getByArea(selectedArea.getId());
        }catch (DAOException e){
            System.out.print("Dao exception: " + e.getCause());
        }
//Just for check:
        for (Personal p:NewObservableList ){
            System.out.println(p.getNombre());
           //The data is fine.
        }

    });
```

But I need to combine with my other filter, any help/guide is fine for me.
and of course sorry for my terrible English.
Saludos!